# Angular 5 build error "Property does not exist on type"

Tags: angular, build, universal

```
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
import { Headers } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class ProjectsService {

  private _wpBase = environment.wpBase;
```

ng build --prod gives me an error :

```
ERROR in src/app/projects/projects.service.ts(11,33): error TS2339: Property 'wpBase' does not exist on type '{ production: boolean; }'.
```

How can I fix this? The app works fine, I'm trying to implement Angular Universal using this guide: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-universal-rendering

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably forgot to set the `wpBase` property in *environment.prod.ts*...

Check both your *environment.ts* and *environment.prod.ts* and see if you have set the `wpBase` correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Quick fix is to type the environment as any:

```
@Injectable()
export class ProjectsService {
  private _wpBase = (environment as any).wpBase;
}
```

Proper fix would be to add type definition for your environment object.

```
interface AppEnv {
   production: boolean;
   wpBase: // whatever is the correct type
}
export const environment: AppEnv = {
  production: false,
  wpBase: // whatever is the value
};
```